# Is handing a cancel with a Context possible?

Tags: project-reactor

I'm working on a server based on GRPC and Java Reactor.

It stamps incoming requests with a request correlation ID and returns a Flux of responses to clients.

The same ID is logged throughout request processing chain with Slf4J [MDC](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html) backed by Logback:

- at request capture
- at request completion
- at request error
  all this with Flux.

I was able to pass correlation ID to Flux event handlers above with [Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context), but there seems to be no way to retrieve it when handling cancellation.

I tried looking for cancellation handlers in the latest Java Reactor [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) that would allow retrieve Context, could not find any.